# How do i get rid of these black marks

Tags: modeling

The wing flaps are 2D planes that i applied a solidify mod on them. how do i remove these black marks/seams?[image]

Comment: Shadows in this case are due to some errors in geometry, hidden / internal faces or custom normals or else something. As there's Subsurf modifier in stack internal faces would be first thing to check, in Edit mode switch to Edge selection mode and run Select All By Trait > Non-Manifold

Answer (score 0):

Add more diffuse light, or lights from other angles, so that ripples don’t make such harsh shadows.

Comment: Lighting won't help in this case since they aren't rendering anything, that is solid mesh is shown on the screenshot.

Comment: You need to edit your post to supply more details and information.  All I know is the low-res screen shot, and they look like shadows from a harsh light source on a wavy material.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to "flat" rather than "smooth", will the black show?

If you switch to " flat" and the black disappear, the solution will be to make more "subdivision" in the "edit mode" and then switch back to "smooth"

Comment: Is this supposed to be a community wiki post?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Edge split modifier and try changing angle
2. Try Applying Subdivision surface modifier
3. if this does not work apply solidify modifierand go to edit mode and re-calculate normals by pressing "Shift + N"